# Webapp to let users choose what RAW pictures I should edit

Tags: photography, information-management

I take all my pictures in RAW, I only want to edit the keepers (obviously) and my users want to make a selection themselves, so pick/discard, flag, rate.

Is there a way to have them do that online? Perhaps trough a web interface?

I just want to know which ones they picked and which ones they want to throw away. Rating would be a plus.

So far I haven't found it. I heard from someone a while back that Lightroom CC has the option to do that with the 20 GB cloud storage you get, but I couldn't find any information on the Adobe site about that, or on YouTube etc.